# If $E$ and $E'$ are $G$-equidecomposable and if $E$ is $G$-paradoxical then so is $E'$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that the following:

> Let $G$ be a group that acts on a set $X$ and assume that $E$ and $E'$
> are $G$-equidecomposable subsets of $X$. If $E$ is $G$-paradoxical
> then so is $E'$.

Here are the definitions that I am working with:

**Definition:** Let $G$ be a group that acts on a set $X$ with the subsets $A$ and $B$. If there exists two sets $\{A_i\}_{i = 1}^k$ and $\{B_i\}_{i = 1}^k$ whose elements make a partition of $A$ and $B$ respectively and if there exists a multi-set $\{g \in G\}_{i = 1}^k$ such that $g_i(A_i) = B_i$ for all $i=1, \ldots, k$ then $A$ is $G$-equidecomposable with $B$ with $k$ pieces.

**Definition:** Let $G$ be a group that acts on a set $X$ och let $E \subseteq X$. We say that $E$ is $G$-paradoxical if there exists $\{A_i \subseteq E\}_{i = 1}^n$ and $\{B_j \subseteq E\}_{j = 1}^m$ whose elements are pairwise disjoint and if there exists two multisets $\{g_i \in G\}_{i = 1}^n$ and $\{g'_j \in G\}_{j = 1}^m$ such that
$$E = \bigcup_{i = 1}^n g_i(A_i) \quad \text{and} \quad E = \bigcup_{j = 1}^m g'_j(B_j)  \quad (1).$$

I can understand why this is true intuitively: if $E$ is paradoxical then I can make a copy of it, and since those copies are equidecomposable with $E'$, I can turn those copies into $E'$. However, how do I show this with these definitions? My approach is to first decompose $E$ into its "pieces" like in equation (1) and then to act with certain $g$'s in $G$ on each "piece" to obtain two copies of $E'$. However, I do not know if this is correct.